# Display number of records in a Model in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-jet

[image]

As shown above, how could I show the number records (10 questions, 7 answers, and 5 rewards) next to the Model name on the Django Admin page?

**EDITED**

For sure, I know override the app_index.html could be a solution, but any better one?

BTW, don't be like a professor or keyboard-man without any suggestion related to the question when you answering others' question. People on stackoverflow definitely know how to Google and read docs.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SachinKukreja Actually, I have no idea right now...

Comment: You should check the [docs](https://jet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dashboard_custom.html) for this. Try yourself first.

Comment: How about modifying the Admin Form in your application? 
Just a little sidenote, you won't get any useful input without code. So better try it yourself first. ;)

Comment: @SachinKukreja r u a professor?

Comment: @Herbert yeah, I tried override the app_index.html and thought that could be a solution. But any built-in way?

Comment: And you should realize if you aren't asking us to debug your code, you are just asking us to do your "homework". Read the question before the edit, what information does it have to even understand where you are stuck!

Comment: @mrhaoji Well, as Sachin Kukreja has said. As long as you don't provide code that we can analyse you won't get suggestions. How about posting your previous attempts to solve the issue?